# Bug with assigning of bounty?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty

This might be my mistake but on the only [bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list) I offered and gave the bounty went to the wrong answer.

That is, I am pretty sure that I intended to give it to one answer, but then I got a comment from the author saying that he is confused as to why I gave it to an old answer of his, rather than to the newer and better answer he wrote due to the bounty (it was the answer to which I intended to give the bounty).

There is very little way for me to trace exactly what happened, and it's not cheap for me to conduct experiments, so I post here to see if others have experienced a similar event. Specifically, there may have been a confusion since the same author had 3 answers. I do not discount that I could have been confused, but if there's some sort of bug, it would be nice to find it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll have to assume that you did indeed misclick, since the server log shows your "award bounty" request to go to the old answer:

[image: screenshot of the log entry]

(note the 4537 in the Uri). I also checked the corresponding JavaScript code, and I can't find any reason whatsoever why it would send the wrong post id to the server.